# Simulink: Possible to connect blocks without creating port to port connection line?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm starting on Simulink and just wondering if it is possible to connect two blocks without actually running an explicit connection line from port to port? Because with system getting larger, these connections create too much jumble and mess.

Like is it possible to give a name to some signal and use that name to specify output of one block, and the same name at input of destination block to show implied connection. Just as how its done in schematic building of for example SPICE tools. Or some other mechanism just to reduce the complexity of connections in model?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with the [*Goto*-block](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/goto.html) and the corresponding [*From*-block](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/from.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Precisely, what I was searching for!

Comment: Although Goto-From blocks can be used, their use is typically frowned upon as they can make it difficult to see the interconnections (and hence signal flow) between blocks.  The preference is to use Buses to group multiple signals into one "line" (then feed that back) to reduce clutter.

Comment: Another method to reduce the ever growing complexity is to use subsystems to group parts of the model. This way you can reduce the amount of blocks in one layer and at the same time make the top-layers more abstract. As @PhilGoddard pointed out, the use of goto/from-blocks can make it very hard to see the signal flow as the model gets bigger. I personally only use it in seldom cases, for example when a connection would actually distract from the signal flow itself (i.e. connecting a *To Workspace*-block or *Scope* at the bottom of the model).

Answer (score 0):

yes of course, when your system get very complicated is it useful to use tags ("go to " tag and "from" tag ) in Simulink without routing explicitly the blocks with lines, tap "go to" in Simulink model and it will show you a small rectangular block, give it a name , and do the same with "from" tag , connect each tag with appropriate port (output port -> "go to", input port -> "from") , you can call these tags from any system or subsystem.
for more information refer to the official documentation :

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/goto.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/from.html?searchHighlight=from%20&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_from%20